# How to do limits approaching infinity with trig?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sin 2x}{x}$$

This is the math problem, but how do I do limits approaching to infinity with trig?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

$$0 \le \left|\frac{\sin 2x}{x}\right| \le \frac{1}{|x|}$$

Comment: Hi Paul, I edited your answer slightly to make the absolute value symbol more pronounced. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: I don't understand this. It looks like the squeeze/sandwich theorem. I understand the squeeze/sandwich theorem, but where are the absolute values and the zeros coming from?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: I'm very appreciated it! Thanks!

Comment: @Kaaagome: Yes. So we can get $\lim_{x\to \infty} \left|\frac{\sin 2x}{x}\right|=0.$ And Notice $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) =0$ is equivalent to $\lim_{x\to x_0}|f(x)| =0$

Comment: Ah. So is the answer zero then? I did the squeeze theorem and on both sides I did get zero. Should I be using this theorem for every trig limit to infinity problem?

Comment: @Kaaagome: Yes, it is!

Comment: @Kaaagome: You are welcome!

Comment: In fact, we don't need the first (trivial) inequality at all; $|f(x)| \le 1/x$ (for $x > 0$) is equivalent to $-1/x \le f(x) \le 1/x$, and then we can apply the squeeze lemma as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @Kaaagome: No, this method will not work for "every trig limit to infinity problem". (That's such a broad class of problems that I'm pretty sure there *is* no single general trick that would work for all of them.) For example, applying $|\sin x|\le1$ won't help you with $\lim_{x\to\infty} x\sin\frac1x$ (although, using $|\sin x|\le|x|$, you can at least get an upper bound). Still, it's a useful trick (e.g.) whenever you have a bounded (or slow-growing) function divided by function that monotonely tends to infinity.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT** $-1 \leq \sin 2x\leq 1$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$

Comment: Yes I did the squeeze/sandwich theorem, is the answer zero then? because on both sides of the theorem, I got zero.

Comment: Yes, precisely! You'll get used to find bounded function and functions going to zero, it's a matter of practice.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $0\le|\sin 2x|\le1\, \forall x$, however as $x\to \infty, \frac1x \to 0$